# Angular 9: TypeScript 'FormData' TS2351: This expression is not constructable. Type 'FormData' has no construct signatures

Tags: angular, typescript

When I do this:

```ts
const formData = new FormData();
```

I get this:

> TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
> Type 'FormData' has no construct signatures.

It works but it throws an error.

Comment: I think it's asking for a type. Try: `const formData: any = new FormData();`

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work either